# Add a className to ::-webkit

Tags: css

I am trying to add a classname into webkit, moz, ms... How can I convert it:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    text-align: center;
}

::-moz-placeholder { 
    text-align: center; 
}

::-ms-input-placeholder { 
    text-align: center;
}
```

into:

```
.form-horizontal {

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    text-align: center;
}

::-moz-placeholder { 
    text-align: center; 
}

::-ms-input-placeholder { 
    text-align: center;
}

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense, please provide more detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just put the class name you want in front of the selector. If you want to nest your selectors like that, use a preprocessor.

```css
.form-horizontal ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    text-align: center;
}

.form-horizontal ::-moz-placeholder { 
    text-align: center; 
}

.form-horizontal ::-ms-input-placeholder { 
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-horizontal">
  <input type="text" placeholder="centered">
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="non centered">
</div>
```